# How to test function that has more than outputs lines

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test a function that has more than outputs lines.

What I want to test is the if of the function. If the condition happens, it will print a string and it will return a key and a value of a dict.

The function is this:

```py
def targe_region(self, bed, chro, position):
    """
    Tool 1: Look is position is covered by the Bed file input.
    """
    for key, value in bed.items():
        if key == chro:
            for values in value:
                if int(position) in range(values[0], values[1]):
                    print("Your position is covered by this bed file")
                    return print(key, values)

            return "Your position is not covered by this bed file"
```

This is part of a big script and the input of this has been added with the test code I show below.

```py
def test_target_region():
    """
    chr20    3    4    Neg2    0    -    127477031    127478198    0,0,255
    chrX    1    50    Neg3    0    -    127478198    127479365    0,0,255
    chrX    50    100    Pos5    0    +    127479365    127480532    255,0,0
    """
    BED = Read_file("./test_bed_file_with_errors4.bed")
    data_loaded = BED.load_data()
    bed_data = Bed_tools(data_loaded)
    user_input2 = "chrX:55"
    chro = user_input2.split(":")[0]
    position = user_input2.split(":")[1]
    assert (
        bed_data.targe_region(data_loaded, chro, position)
        == """Your position is coveraged by this bed file
    chrX [50, 100]"""
    )
```

The output is this:

```
FAILURES =====================================================
______________________________________________________________ 
test_target_region 
______________________________________________________________

    def test_target_region():
        BED = Read_file("./test_bed_file_with_errors4.bed")
        data_loaded = BED.load_data()
        bed_data = Bed_tools(data_loaded)
        user_input2 =  "chrX:55"
        chro = user_input2.split(":")[0]
        position = user_input2.split(":")[1]
>       assert bed_data.targe_region(data_loaded, chro, position) == hola
E       AssertionError: assert None == 'Your position is coveraged by this bed file\nchrX [50, 100]'
E        +  where None = <bound method Bed_tools.targe_region of <BED_toolkit.Class.bed_class.Bed_tools object at 0x7f9c713c0280>>({'chr1': [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], 'chr20': [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 'chrX': [[1, 50], [50, 100]]}, 'chrX', '55')
E        +    where <bound method Bed_tools.targe_region of <BED_toolkit.Class.bed_class.Bed_tools object at 0x7f9c713c0280>> = <BED_toolkit.Class.bed_class.Bed_tools object at 0x7f9c713c0280>.targe_region

test.py:66: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------
Your position is coveraged by this bed file
chrX [50, 100]
=========================================================== short test summary info ============================================================
FAILED test.py::test_target_region - AssertionError: assert None == 'Your position is coveraged by this bed file\nchrX [50, 100]'
```

What can I do to match the Captured stdout call with my test

Comment: there 'Your position is coveraged by this bed file\nchrX [50, 100]' is not actually a return of the function. So you cant assert that. I recomend you to make a funtion that returns the `key, val` if it's occupied and `None` if not. Then you make the print outside the function. That way you can assert with theese values (`key,val` or `None` ). Remember returning a print isn't a good idea, because the value of return would be a None.

Answer (score 0):

Pytest provides [different fixures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) that allow you to capture the output of a test function.

So, assuming your current test triggers the `if` statement, you could take advantage of the `capfd` fixture like this:

```py
def test_target_region(capfd):
    """
    chr20    3    4    Neg2    0    -    127477031    127478198    0,0,255
    chrX    1    50    Neg3    0    -    127478198    127479365    0,0,255
    chrX    50    100    Pos5    0    +    127479365    127480532    255,0,0
    """
    BED = Read_file("./test_bed_file_with_errors4.bed")
    data_loaded = BED.load_data()
    bed_data = Bed_tools(data_loaded)
    user_input2 = "chrX:55"
    chro = user_input2.split(":")[0]
    position = user_input2.split(":")[1]

    captured = capfd.readouterr()
    bed_data.targe_region(data_loaded, chro, position)
    assert (
        captured.out
        == """Your position is coveraged by this bed file
    chrX [50, 100]"""
    )
```